# How to create and drop temporary table on Oracle from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

Is there a way to create and drop a temporary table on Oracle from SQL Server (T-SQL) stored procedure?

I am working on a stored procedure on SQL Server, where I need to send data rows from SQL Server to Oracle in order to perform some joins and updates on Oracle end.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to create rows on the Oracle side if the procedure is in sql server? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep it all in one place? Maybe create your temp table on the sql side and then a couple queries or whatever to update it.

Comment: The table to be updated is located on Oracle and is about 2.5 millions rows big. The data rows need to be referenced are on SQL Server and are much smaller in size. Due to business concern, I am required to create the stored procedure on SQL Server instead of on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean Lange already said, it makes more sence to keep the data in one place. But if you need it anyway, here you go:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table1
(
  col1 VARCHAR2(15),
  col2 NUMBER
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm)

Comment: Thanks. But how do I do the same from a stored procedure on SQL Server? I know how to use OPENQUERY for operations like select, insert, update and delete, but cannot find any example online for creating tables.

Comment: 1. Check the permissions (GRANT CREATE TABLE); 2. Oracle does't like CREATE statements from stored procedures, try EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ...'.